# Retrieving an element value from a form present several times in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using server side code Im creating several forms using the same class to prevent the submit using jquery, this forms have a select box and depending of their value i make something.

```
<form class="fooForm">
  <select name="fooBox">
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>

<form class="fooForm">
  <select name="fooBox">
    <option value="bar11">bar11</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>

<form class="fooForm">
  <select name="fooBox">
    <option value="bar22">bar22</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(".fooForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //How do I read the value of he current selectbox ???
    });
</script>
```

A this point I wonder, is this valid html? And how do I read the value of the seletbox from the form that is trying to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd><sub>[image: Fiddle]</sub></kbd>
*jQuery*

```
$(".fooForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).children('select').val());
    alert($(this).children('select').val());
});
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The form that was submitted is stored in `this`, and the selectbox can be found by wrapping the element in a jQuery container and applying `.find()`. The value of a select is retrieved with `.val()`.

```
$( this ).find( 'select' ).val();
```

As for the validity of the HTML, run it through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). (It is.)